# How can I speed up my Python Code by multiprocessing (parallel-processing)?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, netcdf

The function of my python code is very straightforward. It reads the netCDF file through a file list and returns the mean value in this case.

However, it takes time to read the netCDF file. I am wondering can I speedup this process by Multiprocessing (parallel-processing) since my work station has 32-core processors.

The code looks like:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

for i in filerange:
    print "Reading the",i, "file", "Wait"
    infile_Radar = Dataset(file_list[i],'r')

    # Read the hourly Data
    Radar_rain=np.array(infile_Radar.variables['rain'][:])

    for h in range(0,24):
        hourly_rain = Radar_rain[h,:]
        hourly_mean[i,h] = np.mean(hourly_rain)

np.savetxt('Hourly_Spatial_mean.txt', hourly_mean, delimiter='\t')
```

Since the reading file is independet to each other, so how can make the best of my work station? Thanks.

Comment: Threading, rather than multiprocessing, seems more appropriate for an IO-bound task.

Comment: There is many way to distribute the process, however, you must make sure the output doesn't overwrite each other .

Comment: I don't see where you read files. You can get some improvement by overlapping reads on one stream with processing another, but that scale-up only goes so far.

Comment: I edited the codes. @tdelaney.  The overwrite can be fixed using a unique indicator. But I don't know the way to distribute the process. Could you give me some hints.@mootmoot

Comment: Explain this more: _"reading file is independet to each other"_.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for a fairly standard threading implementation.  Assuming that it's the Dataset constructor that's the blocking part you may want to do something like this:

```
from threading import Thread

def CreateDataset( offset, files, datasets ):
   datasets[offset] = Dataset( files[i], 'r' )


threads   = [None] * len( filerange )
data_sets = [None] * len( filerange )

for i in filerange:
   threads[i] = Thread( None, CreateDataset, None, ( i, file_list, data_sets ) )
   threads[i].start();

for t in threads:
   t.join()

# Resume work with each item in the data_sets list
print "All Done";
```

Then for each dataset do the rest of the work you detailed.  Wherever the actual "slow stuff" is, that's the basic approach.